# How do I write this expression in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

It is simple to write data-bind expression like:

```
<span data-bind="text: userName"></span>
```

But I want to include Hello before userName so the span should look like:

Hello World

where World is userName

How can I write this in data binding expression?

**Note:** Please do not suggest that I move Hello out of span and write it statically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout can bind expressions too:

```
<span data-bind="text: 'hello ' + userName()"></span>
```